# Column alias name doesn't work in SQL fiddle

Tags: mysql, alias, sqlfiddle

I am trying to execute a simple query on SQL Fiddle

```
select name as 'user_name' from user_data;
```

But in the output, the column's alias name is not showing. Instead of showing **user_name**, it is just showing simply as **name**.

But when i print a simple query like this..

```
Select 1 as 'one',2 as 'old'
```

For the above query, it is showing correct output means Alias name are being displayed.

I have already tried these queries..

```
select name as user_name from user_data;

select name user_name from user_data;

select name 'user_name' from user_data;
```

Here is a live [**link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa0ee/2).

So i want to know if there is something wrong with my query or it's just a SQL Fiddle limitation?

> **Note:** I am using MySql 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Remove **Apex** from your alias column:

```
select name as user_name from user_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

All this selects is correct:

```
Select ud.1 as one, ud.2 as old from user_data as ud;
Select 1 as one, 2 as old from user_data as ud;
Select 1 one, 2 old from user_data;
Select 1 `one more`, 2 old from user_data;
Select 1 one_more, 2 old from user_data;
```

Don't use ' separator for column names. You can also use ` if you need to add spaces to column name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `as` keyword. It works just like this:

```
SELECT name user_name FROM user_table
```